# Does the collation of ENUM columns impact their size?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-8.0, enum, mariadb-10.5

What does it mean when we say that an `ENUM` has a charset of `utf8mb4`, versus `latin1`?

My understanding is that the `ENUM` holds a numeric index (1, 2, 3, 4...) that identifies which of the `ENUM` values (abc, def, ghi, jkl...).
If I use `utf8mb4` for an `ENUM` column, is the column using more storage than it would if I used `latin1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference.

`ENUM` is stored as a 1- or 2-byte number, where 0 maps to the first item in your list.  You deal with the column as a string, but the disk only sees a number.

2-bytes is used only when there are more than 255 options.  There are some who shun the use of ENUM altogether; there are some who frown on more than a few options.  I say use ENUM for a small, unlikely to change, list of options.

It may be possible to get charset or collation problems if you aren't consistent in database and connection specifications.